# Buffer() deprecation warning when using Buffer.concat()

Tags: node.js, buffer

My only use of `Buffer` is `Buffer.concat()` like this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const stream = new Writable()
    const chunks = []
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
    stream._write = (chunk, enc, next) => {
      chunks.push(chunk)
      next()
    }
    stream.on('finish', (chunk) => {
      resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks))
    })
    stream.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error('Error writing to stream', e)
      reject(e)
    })

    PImage.encodePNGToStream(img1, stream)
  })
```

Yet Node gives this warning:

> ERROR  (node:8) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

Is there something wrong with using `Buffer.concat()` this way, or should I just ignore the warning?

Comment: Your usage looks fine, the warning is probably the underlying library - https://github.com/joshmarinacci/node-pureimage/issues/161